# C Program for Pyramid

Tags: c

this is my code for pyramid of asterisks but my output is different from the given output by our instructor. It has spaces inside and underscores both left and right. Someone please help

```
_ _ _ _ * _ _ _ _

_ _ _ * * * _ _ _

_ _ * * * * * _ _

_ * * * * * * * _

* * * * * * * * *
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 int num,s,co,tt=1;
 printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 printf("\n");
 for(; num>=1; num--,tt++)
 {
  for(s=1; s<=num; s++)
    printf("_");
  for(co=tt; co>1; co--)
    printf("*");
  for(co=tt; co>1; co--)
    printf("*");
  for(co=num; co>=1; co--)
    printf("_");
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include what output you *do* get and where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Instead it was on odd numbers sir as what I have given above, my output is on even so it was starting with 2 asterisks, 4, 6,8 and so on sir. should I printscreen in out sir?

Comment: Edit your question with this information. If possible include the tree.

Comment: Please learn how to ask a question... 1) What is your input? 2) What is your expected output? 3) What is your actual output?

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [Ask]. [Edit] your question to include your output and an explicit statement why you think your output isn't correct. Do not post screen snap-shorts, copy and paste the text from your console window. You might have to enable that feature with system menu of the console window where you run your program. Tell your instructor that the whole world says that the Borland compiler should be burnt at the stake. It's over 20 years out of date. You don't need the `conio.h` header in your program.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the pyramid pattern, number of asterisks(`*`) should print 2 more than previous loop and number of underscore(`_`) should print `2` less than previous loop.

Since you had 2 for loops for printing asterisks, your pyramid was starting from `2`.

Consider the below code as an example.

```
int main()
{
   int num,co;
   printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   printf("\n");
  int asterisk = 1;
  for(; num>=1; num--)
  {
    for(co=0; co<num; co++)
      printf("_");
    for(co=0; co<asterisk ; co++)
      printf("*");
    asterisk +=2; //Increase the number of asterisk by 2. 
    for(co=num; co>=1; co--)
      printf("_");
    printf("\n");
  }
   return 0;
 }
```

output:

```
Enter loop repeat number(rows): 10

__________*__________
_________***_________
________*****________
_______*******_______
______*********______
_____***********_____
____*************____
___***************___
__*****************__
_*******************_
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want `2*num + 1` chars on each line and a total of `num` lines. For that use a nested loop like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) exit(1);
    int linelen = 2*num+1;  // Number of chars per line
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0; i < num; ++i)  // Number of lines
    {
        for(int j=0; j < linelen; ++j) // Number of chars per line
        {
            if (j < num-i)
                printf("_");
            else if (j >= num-i && j <= num+i)
                printf("*");
            else 
                printf("_");
        }
        printf("\n");   // Line finished - go to a newline
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
42
```

**Output**

```
__________________________________________*__________________________________________
_________________________________________***_________________________________________
________________________________________*****________________________________________
_______________________________________*******_______________________________________
______________________________________*********______________________________________
_____________________________________***********_____________________________________
____________________________________*************____________________________________
___________________________________***************___________________________________
__________________________________*****************__________________________________
_________________________________*******************_________________________________
________________________________*********************________________________________
_______________________________***********************_______________________________
______________________________*************************______________________________
_____________________________***************************_____________________________
____________________________*****************************____________________________
___________________________*******************************___________________________
__________________________*********************************__________________________
_________________________***********************************_________________________
________________________*************************************________________________
_______________________***************************************_______________________
______________________*****************************************______________________
_____________________*******************************************_____________________
____________________*********************************************____________________
___________________***********************************************___________________
__________________*************************************************__________________
_________________***************************************************_________________
________________*****************************************************________________
_______________*******************************************************_______________
______________*********************************************************______________
_____________***********************************************************_____________
____________*************************************************************____________
___________***************************************************************___________
__________*****************************************************************__________
_________*******************************************************************_________
________*********************************************************************________
_______***********************************************************************_______
______*************************************************************************______
_____***************************************************************************_____
____*****************************************************************************____
___*******************************************************************************___
__*********************************************************************************__
_***********************************************************************************_
```